# Inserting a Hard Coded Value Into a Table

Tags: hardcode

I'm looking to understand how I can insert a hard coded value into a table during an insert of a specific pull of data.  The code below should give an idea of what I am trying to do...It's basically grab a certain set of UserIDs and drop them into another Table and hardcode a value called 'Trial' into the column next to the UserID.

Is something like this easy/possible?

```
Insert Into LastSubscriptionWasTrial (UserId,**'HARDCODEVALUEHERE'**)
SELECT UserId
FROM  ....(Pulling my list of UserIDs here)
```

Answer (score 1):

As originally written your `INSERT` statement is missing its `VALUES` specifier, so it's looking for a column name when it finds 'Trial'. It's unclear whether UserId is a column or a variable name so I can't suggest a correct statement.

Answer (score 0):

unless I am totally missing something from your question you should be able to do the following, you just have to put the value you want hard coded in your statement.

```
Insert Into LastSubscriptionWasTrial (UserId, TrialField)
SELECT UserId, 'Trial' FROM ....(Pulling my list of UserIDs here)
```

Comment: That was my thought as well, but I always get this result: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near 'Trial'.

Comment: What is the datatype on the field for the 'Trial'?

Comment: I believe I've solved my problem by using my select statement...So I still have my insert, but went about it like this: InsertInto Table (column1, column2)  values ((select value1 from (select....),Value2))